# Is it possible to hide a child element with parent of parent element?

Tags: javascript, css, hide, element, fadeout

```
<div class="grandma">
    <span class="file-name">file name</span> 
    <span class="percent">100%</span> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="upload-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As "upload-success" appears on the screen, I want to fade out "upload-success" in few seconds with "grandma" and everything inside of "grandma".

I don't know much about js yet so I wonder if it's possible to do it.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does `upload-success` appear on the screen? If it does happen within a callback function, you could `setTimeout` to disappear the grandparent element in few seconds.

Comment: when exactly does "upload-success" appear?

Comment: does this do what you were trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/73t6gj33/1/  just the trigger event needs to be modified according to your requirement

Comment: @HashemQolami I'm using a wordpress plugin which let users upload their files. "upload-success" appears when upload is completed. It's a progress bar. Actually "grandma" appears first and as soon as upload is completed, "upload-success" appears then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) you can fade that like this:

```js
$(".upload-success").parent().parent().fadeOut(2000); //2000 milliseconds
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandma">
    <span class="file-name">file name</span> 
    <span class="percent">100%</span> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="upload-success"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a genius simple line! Thank you so much. It seems working just fine. I thought It'd have been more complicated. Thank you!